# Add IDataErrorInfo to entities

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, idataerrorinfo

I'm developping a WPF Application With MVVM.
I'm using Entity Framework to generate entities from data base.
I want to implement a validation to my UserControls (binded to my entities) by implemening the IDataErrorInfo interface. but i don't know how to add method implementation of IDataErrorInfo  with entities.

Can you help me to do this ?
thx

Answer (score 1):

The generated classes are partial classes, so you can extend them by specifying them in an additional class file:

```
namespace SomeEntityModelNamespace {
    public partial class SomeEntityType : IDataErrorInfo    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

Still, i have made the experience that binding directly to entities is not always a good idea. I usually create a view model reflecting its properties with appropriate methods to update the actual database object (as i like to have my ObjectContext as short-lived as possible)